# calling a.NET web service from inside a pdf file

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I'm working on a mini project in which I need to insert 'the number of parts in stock' dynamically and display it on the pdf page(probably in a control??) I have a web service i can call to get the number of parts in stock.

Is there a way that, when a pdf file loads we can make a call to the web service, returning the number of parts in stock....and display it on the pdf page?

If so, what controls can i use and what tools will i Need?

Greatly appreciate any help on this...Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have a template pdf file already, or are you working one up from scratch?

Comment: Jimmy - I already have a pdf file that i have to work with for this

Comment: From reading the web, I believe you can do it using Live Cycle Designer (which I don't know a great deal about). I was going to suggest loading the page into iText and painting over the correct details. Sorry not to be any help

Comment: Jimmy - That's Alright. I came across the LCD too. I just don't know yet what i can do with it. Thanks for taking time to research on this. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LiveCycle Designer can be used to generate a XFA-based PDF form which can behave that way (call a webservice via SOAP, then populate fields with the results). Although you need to 'Reader-extend' the PDF so that it can call the services when opened with Adobe Reader, otherwise will only work on Acrobat.

Comment: do you mind providing any explanation or source on how to do this? I've been trying to populate a simple dropdown list using sharepoint's web-services for quite some time with no results. adobe documentation doesn't really help me.